# Standard errors propensity score matching

Tags: regression, panel-data, standard-error, causality, propensity-scores

I am currently working on a causal inference project via several panel regression specifications, and one of the methods I'm using to obtain more robust results is propensity score matching (PSM). For the regular regression specifications (i.e. not PSM), I am using clustered standard errors to account for dependence within certain groups.

I was wondering which standard errors I should be using for the propensity score matched sample in Python? Are there any robust standard errors for this scenario implemented in Python? I did come across this paper from [Abadie et al.](https://www.nber.org/papers/w15301.pdf) (2016), but have not been able to find an implementation yet.

Comment: See my answer about this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/492788). I don't know Python so I can't help with specific code.